# Cordova Facebook login problem with this plugin https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Tags: cordova, phonegap

What is wrong in my code? I already install cordova-plugin-facebook4 
and I also give proper APP_ID and APP_NAME which I got from developers.facebook.com.

I'm new in PhoneGap Project.

Error:

```
1.  Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://staticxx.facebook.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:16

2. (index):32 Uncaught ReferenceError: facebooConnectPlugin is not defined
    at LoginWithFB ((index):32)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):23)
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>


        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <button type="button" onclick="LoginWithFB()" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: blue;padding:5%;" >Login With Facebook</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function LoginWithFB()
            {
                alert('Function Start Here');

                facebooConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile','email'],function(result){ 
                    alert('You Completed 1st Stage');
                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                    alert('Now Going To The Next Step');

                    //Success Login Function 
                    facebooConnectPlugin.api("me?fields=email,name,picture",['public_profile','email'],function(userData){
                        alert('Sorry You Completed Last Round Too..Now You Could Be Logged IN');
                        alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
                    },function(error){
                        alert('Hurrey You Got Erorr 2');
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                    });
                    //Last Error Function 
                },function(error){
                    alert('Hurrey You Got A Error');
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                });

                alert('Function End  Here');

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cordova-plugin-facebook4 is not working

use phonegap-facebook-plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap-facebook-plugin

install using code

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

Hope it helps!